# Remove trailing zeroes in date in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am using the current format in order to product a JavaScript date:

```
var date = visitdate;
var newdate = date.split("/").reverse().join("-");
```

I would expect this to return 1900-01-01 for example, however what this actually returns is 1900-01-0100.

Iv'e tried using slice in order to trim this off but this just ends up slicing off the day instead and still adds the zeros. There seems to be no way of getting rid of them. Is there anyway to remove them?

Comment: What is the value of `visitdate` for your demo?

Comment: It can change depending on the value pulled from the database, however in this example the exact value stored in SQL is 1900/01/01 00:00

Comment: I'd expect you actually get a `newdate` of `"01 00:00-01-1900"` from that input

Comment: @LianeStevenson Then you need to first `split` the string by space and then use `/` split

Comment: PaulS. the date is not outputted in that format - it's 1900-01-0100 - Tushar I tried that - that just took away the day and still added the zeroes

Comment: @LianeStevenson Please check your data and the code you've really used to get the result ("`1900-01-0100`"), and update the post. With the information given in the post, the result really is what Paul S. says.

Comment: For some reason it isn't though - the final on screen value of the date is 1900-01-0100 I'm aware it shouldn't be, but for some reason it is..

Comment: check [DateX](https://github.com/foo123/DateX) which makes date parsing, formating and validation intuitive (author)

Comment: The code in the post and the data given in a comment [gives you "`01 00:00-01-1900`"](http://jsfiddle.net/1960bjah/)  for sure. Are you sure there's not more code forming the results when showing the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may write a function like below and whatever format needed you can change

```
      function formatDate(date) {
      var hours = date.getHours();
      var minutes = date.getMinutes();
      var ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'pm' : 'am';
      hours = hours % 12;
      hours = hours ? hours : 12; // the hour '0' should be '12'
      hours = hours < 10 ? '0'+hours : hours;
      minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0'+minutes : minutes;
      var strTime = hours + ':' + minutes + ' ' + ampm;

      var Month = date.getMonth()+1 < 10 ? '0'+(date.getMonth()+1) : date.getMonth()+1;
      var Date = date.getDate() < 10 ? '0'+date.getDate() : date.getDate();
      var strDate = Month + "/" + Date + "/" + date.getFullYear();
      return strDate + " " + strTime;
    }
```

Or in your case if you dont want time just remove strTime from return of function

Comment: I think the `visitdate` for OP is actually just a string, not a `Date` with it's function.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the input is "01/01/1900 00:00" - add a .split(" ") in between like this:

```
"01/01/1900 00:00".split(" ")[0].split("/").reverse().join("-");
```

Or just skip the reverse() if your input is like you said "1900-01-01":

```
"1900/01/01 00:00".split(" ")[0].split("/").join("-");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also extract the information from your date string by using a regex like this:

```
var d = '1990/01/01 00:00';
var matches = d.match(/^(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d+) (\d+):(\d+)$/);
if(matches){
  var year    = matches[1]
    , month   = matches[2]
    , day     = matches[3]
    , hour    = matches[4]
    , minutes = matches[5];
  console.log(year+'-'+month+'-'+day);
}
```